# Error C3918: Error wile checking event for being nullptr

Tags: .net, events, delegates, c++-cli

I have delegate and event in my .h file

```
delegate void ResponseReceivedHandler(System::Object^ sender, WhoisEventArgs^ e);
event ResponseReceivedHandler^ ResponseReceived;
```

somewhere in my code I want to check if event is `nullptr` or no, but when I write

**EDITED:**

```
if (this->ResponseReceived != nullptr)
{
     this->ResponseReceived(this, e);
}
```

Error occurred

> Error 1   error C3918: usage requires
>   'VT::WhoisClient::WhoisRequest::ResponseReceived'
>   to be a data
>   member    c:\Users\ViToBrothers\Desktop\ViTo
>   Projects\VT.WhoisClient\VT.WhoisClient\VT.WhoisRequest.cpp    50

What can I do ?

Comment: The code you wrote looks like C#, not C++/CLI.

Comment: I get example from the C# and want to change to C++ .NET ...

Comment: maybe there is no need to write if (this.ResponseReceived != null) this line

Comment: `this.` doesn't work in C++.  `this` is a pointer.  pointers are used with `->`.  You need to use the correct C++ syntax or you will get compile errors.

Comment: Oh sorry I corrected ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that in this case, the compiler is generating the accessor functions and backing storage for the event handler delegate.  Thus, it is not necessary for you to check for null.

See more here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4b612y2s.aspx

Comment: And the documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4b612y2s.aspx) explains how to raise events.