# Observer pattern in c++/cli for mixed managed/unmanaged

Tags: c++-cli, observer-pattern, mixed-mode

I have a system comprising a C# UI, a C++/CLI mixed mode interop wrapper, and some native c++ projects.

What I need to do is set up a system such that the native c++ code can send a log message, and the UI can report it.

I set up a native IObservable using [this](http://rtmatheson.com/2010/03/working-on-the-subject-observer-pattern/) as a template, but then the C# code can't be an observer. My thought was to set up another observer pattern in C++/CLI, which observes the native observer, and to let the C# implement that.  I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1249517/super-simple-example-of-c-sharp-observer-observable-with-delegates) as a template but I'm struggling to convert this into valid C++/CLI.

```
ref class Observable
{
public:
Observable(void);
virtual ~Observable(void);

event System::EventHandler^ SomethingHappened;

void DoSomething() {
    System::EventHandler^ handler = SomethingHappened;
    //if (handler != nullptr)
    //{
        handler(this, System::EventArgs::Empty);
    //}//null check not permitted in C++/CLI
};
```

Gives the error: C3918: requires SomethingHappened to be a data member.  [This is the MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/w901cc8a%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) - but I can't identify what I'm doing wrong.

Any suggestions?

Thanks,
Melanie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to use C# syntax.  Events work a little differently in C++/CLI, they have a *[raise](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235237.aspx)* accessor in addition to the add and remove accessor.  In other words, a method that fires the event.  The compiler auto-generates one if you don't provide your explicit version it.  That makes raising the event very simple:

```
void DoSomething() {
    SomethingHappened(this, System::EventArgs::Empty);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In C++/Cli, you do not need to check the event for null (and you can't) when using "trivial events".  The language takes care of that for you.

See related:
[Error C3918: Error wile checking event for being nullptr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6034720/error-c3918-error-wile-checking-event-for-being-nullptr)
[Does C++/CLI event have any listeners?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8413109/does-c-cli-event-have-any-listeners)

So, for your case, just remove the `nullptr` check

Comment: thanks, and those are useful links - but I get the same error when I remove the null check.

Answer (score 0):

Using [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58cwt3zh%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), the right thing to do is to fire the event directly.  Like this:

```
void DoSomething() {       
    SomethingHappened(this, System::EventArgs::Empty);
}
```