# Observer pattern from native c++ to c++/cli

Tags: c#, c++-cli, observer-pattern

I have a piece of code written in (native) c++ and now I have to integrate it with a C# GUI application. I already built the wrapper in c++/cli, and I can successfully communicate with the native piece of code through this wrapper. The problem, however, is that this native c++ code uses the [Observer Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern), and I can't make it to work. I had a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15779209/6570821) similar question but that solves the notification from the c++/cli component up to the c# application through a delegate. I can't observe the native from to the wrapper instead.

Here's a skeleton of what I have. I'll leave some classes implementations since they are not useful in this scope.

---

### observer_interface.h

This is a simple interface that each observer needs to implement. This is in the native part.

```
class observer_interface
{
public:
    virtual void implement_me(observe_me *o) = 0;
}
```

---

### observe_me.h and .cpp

This is the native piece of code. It maintains a list of observers, and have two public methods that allow the registration/deregistration of observers. It has another public method that I can call.

```
class observe_me
{
protected:
    vector<observer_interface*> observers;
    void notifySomething() {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < observers.size(); i++)
            observers[i].implmement_me(this);
    }

public:
    void registerObserver(observer_interface*);
    void deregisterObserver(observer_interface*);
    int thisIsFine() {
        return 12345;
    }
}
```

---

### observerWrapper.h and .cpp

This is the wrapper in c++/cli, and this is the class that needs to observe the `observe_me` class,

```
public ref class observerWrapper
{
event System::EventHandler^ implement_me_event;

protected:
    observe_me *o;

public:
    // Constructor & destructor
    observerWrapper() {
        o = new observe_me();
        o->registerObserver(this); // <--- this gives me error
    }
    ~observerWrapper() {
        delete o;
    }

    // Let's call the native method
    int thisIsFine() {
        return o->thisIsFine();
    };

    // This should be called by the native c++
    void implement_me() {
        implement_me_event(this, System::EventArgs::Empty);
    }
}
```

---

### frmMain.cs

This is the GUI that should finally receive the notification through the event in the wrapper.

```
public partial class frmMain : Form
{
    observerWrapper o = new observerWrapper();

    public frmMain()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        o.implement_me_event += implement_me;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(o.thisIsFine());
    }

    public void implement_me(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Finally solved!");
    }
}
```

I can't implement the `observer_interface` in the `observerWrapper`, nor I can register it as observer without making it `observer_interface` compliant. How do I solve?

Comment: The compiler stops you from shooting your leg off.  The value of `this` randomly changes when the garbage collector compacts the heap.  But the GC cannot update the pointer in observe_me::observers, it does not know it exists.  Your observer object must be pinned or must be native.  Pinning for that long is very unwise.  Consider using `gcroot<>` to call an internal method of observerWrapper when the callback occurs.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks for your suggestion, but I really fail to see how it can be used in this case and how it can help me.Currently I cannot get the callback from the unmanaged code back to the wrapper, because I cannot find a way to register the wrapper as an observer. I was looking a way to solve that problem first (is possible to solve this in first place?). Do I have to abandon the idea and change the structure of the projects? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for an answer also as it's my first time working with C++/CLI. So all this native managed and unmanaged combo was bit confusing to me as i come from (standard) C++.

In a nutshell:
Ref classes cannot inherit non-ref classes. And non-ref classes cannot have normal reference or pointer to a ref class because it's in garbage collected heap, which relocates objects. Once it's relocated, stored reference/pointer will keep pointing to the same place which contains something else. This is where [gcroot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/dotnet/how-to-hold-object-reference-in-unmanaged-memory?view=vs-2019) comes.

In your C++/CLI wrapper you need to have non-ref class that will implement observer pattern. That class should somehow have or obtain managed reference to the ref class  which it can keep with `gcroot` member. This `gcroot` member reference will be the bridge between unmanaged and managed code. Here's a working code.

There is also [object pinning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/extensions/pin-ptr-cpp-cli?view=vs-2019) in gc heap but you cannot keep the object pinned for the whole life of the process, as pinning have to be done in some function on stack. I imagine that sort of thing could be possible but it's bad design and bad performance.

#### Native dll written in pure C++ (unmanaged), observable class and observer interface:

```
// PureCppDll.h
#include "stdafx.h"
#ifdef PURECPPDLL_EXPORTS
    #define PURECPPDLL_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
    #define PURECPPDLL_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

struct PURECPPDLL_API Feature
{
    int val;
};

class PURECPPDLL_API IFeatureObserver
{
    public:
        virtual ~IFeatureObserver() = default;

        virtual void onFeatureUpdate(Feature* feature) = 0; // observer takes ownership of the feature
};


class PURECPPDLL_API NativeDllAPI
{
    public:
        virtual ~NativeDllAPI() = default;

        virtual void addFeatureObserver(IFeatureObserver* observer) = 0;
        virtual void removeFeatureObserver(IFeatureObserver* observer) = 0;
};

class PURECPPDLL_API NativeDllApiFactory
{
    public:
        static NativeDllAPI* create();
};
```

#### C++/CLI dll code, wiring native (unmanaged) dll and C#:

```
// FeatureObserver.h
#pragma once

#include "PureCppDll.h"
#include <vcclr.h>


namespace CppCLI
{
    ref class CppCLIWrapper;

    class FeatureObserver : public IFeatureObserver
    {
        public:
            FeatureObserver(CppCLIWrapper^ cppcliwrapper);
            ~FeatureObserver();

            void onFeatureUpdate(Feature* feature) override;

        private:
            gcroot<CppCLIWrapper^> m_cppCliWrapper;
    };

}
```

```
//FeatureObserver.cpp
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "FeatureObserver.h"
#include "CppCLIWrapper.h"

namespace CppCLI
{
    FeatureObserver::FeatureObserver(CppCLIWrapper^ cppcliwrapper)
        : m_cppCliWrapper{ cppcliwrapper }
    {

    }

    FeatureObserver::~FeatureObserver()
    {
        System::Console::WriteLine("~FeatureObserver : dieded.");
    }

    void FeatureObserver::onFeatureUpdate(Feature * feature)
    {
        System::Console::WriteLine("FeatureObserver : onFeatureUpdate.");
        m_cppCliWrapper->NotifyFeatureChange(feature);
    }
}
```

```
// CppCLIWrapper.h
#pragma once

#include "ManagedObject.h"
#include "PureCppDll.h"
#include "FeatureObserver.h"

#include <memory>


using namespace System;

namespace CppCLI 
{
    public ref class CppCLIWrapper
    {
        public:
            CppCLIWrapper();
            ~CppCLIWrapper();
            !CppCLIWrapper();

            // slot:
            void NotifyFeatureChange(Feature* feature);

            // signal:
            event EventHandler<MyFeatureEventArgs^>^ FeatureChangedEvent;

        private:
            NativeDllAPI* m_nativeDllApi;
            FeatureObserver* m_featureObserver;
    };
}
```

```
//CppCLIWrapper.cpp
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "CppCLIWrapper.h"

using namespace System;

namespace CppCLI
{
    CppCLIWrapper::CppCLIWrapper()
        : m_nativeDllApi { NativeDllApiFactory::create() }
        , m_featureObserver{ new FeatureObserver{this} }
    {
        m_nativeDllApi->addFeatureObserver(m_featureObserver);
    }

    CppCLIWrapper::~CppCLIWrapper()
    {
        if (m_nativeDllApi != nullptr)
        {
            m_nativeDllApi->removeFeatureObserver(m_featureObserver);
            delete m_nativeDllApi;
        }

        if (m_featureObserver != nullptr)
        {
            delete m_featureObserver;
        }

        System::Console::WriteLine("~CppCLIWrapper : dieded");
    }

    CppCLIWrapper::!CppCLIWrapper()
    {
        if (m_nativeDllApi != nullptr)
        {
            m_nativeDllApi->removeFeatureObserver(m_featureObserver);
            delete m_nativeDllApi;
        }

        if (m_featureObserver != nullptr)
        {
            delete m_featureObserver;
        }

        System::Console::WriteLine("!CppCLIWrapper : finalized");
    }

    void CppCLIWrapper::NotifyFeatureChange(Feature * feature)
    {
        System::Console::WriteLine("CppCLIWrapper : NotifyFeatureChange {0}", feature->val);

        auto myfeat = gcnew MyFeature{};
        auto myfeatargs = gcnew MyFeatureEventArgs{};

        myfeat->Value = feature->val;
        myfeatargs->Feature = myfeat;

        FeatureChangedEvent(this, myfeatargs);
        delete feature;
    }
}
```

#### The DataModel class library in C# for event raising from C++/CLI to C#:

```
using System;

namespace DataModel
{
    public class MyFeature
    {
        public int Value { get; set; }
    }

    public class MyFeatureEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public MyFeature Feature { get; set; }
    }
}
```

#### Finally, C# console application:

```
// Test.cs
using System;
using CppCLI;


namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Starting C++/CLI wrapper for native code.");
            Console.WriteLine("Thread will start producing and notifying Feature objects.");
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to stop.");

            CppCLIWrapper cli = new CppCLIWrapper();
            cli.FeatureChangedEvent += onFeatureChangedEvent;

            Console.ReadKey();
            Console.WriteLine("Program ending...");
        }
    }
}
```

I know it's an old question, I hope this helps someone.

Here's also the code for NativeDllApi class, in case you want to test it.

```
// PureCppDll.cpp

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "PureCppDll.h"

#include <thread>
#include <mutex>

class NativeDllAPIImpl : public NativeDllAPI
{
public:
    NativeDllAPIImpl();
    ~NativeDllAPIImpl();

    // Inherited via NativeDllAPI
    virtual void addFeatureObserver(IFeatureObserver* observer) override;
    virtual void removeFeatureObserver(IFeatureObserver* observer) override;

    void run();

private:
    void NotifyObservers();

private:
    std::mutex m_mutex;
    int m_value;
    bool m_work;
    std::thread m_worker;

    std::vector<IFeatureObserver*> m_observers;
};

NativeDllAPI* NativeDllApiFactory::create()
{
    return new NativeDllAPIImpl{};
}

NativeDllAPIImpl::NativeDllAPIImpl()
    : NativeDllAPI {}
    , m_value{ 42 }
    , m_work{ true }
    , m_worker{&NativeDllAPIImpl::run, this}
{

}

NativeDllAPIImpl::~NativeDllAPIImpl()
{
    std::cout << "~NativeDllAPIImpl : destroying...\n";
    m_work = false;

    if (m_worker.joinable())
    {
        std::cout << "~NativeDllAPIImpl : join thread....\n";
        m_worker.join();
    }

    std::cout << "~NativeDllAPIImpl : dieded...\n";
}

void NativeDllAPIImpl::addFeatureObserver(IFeatureObserver* observer)
{
    std::cout << "NativeDllAPIImpl : addFeatureObserver\n";
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock{ m_mutex };
    m_observers.push_back(observer);
}

void NativeDllAPIImpl::removeFeatureObserver(IFeatureObserver* observer)
{
    std::cout << "NativeDllAPIImpl : removeFeatureObserver\n";
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock{ m_mutex };
    m_observers.erase(std::remove(m_observers.begin(), m_observers.end(), observer), m_observers.end());
}

void NativeDllAPIImpl::run()
{
    std::cout << "NativeDllAPIImpl : Running...\n";

    while (m_work)
    {
        NotifyObservers();
        Sleep(3000);
    }
}

void NativeDllAPIImpl::NotifyObservers()
{
    std::cout << "NativeDllAPIImpl : Notifying observers with value: " << m_value << '\n';
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock{ m_mutex };
    for (auto observer : m_observers)
    {
        observer->onFeatureUpdate(new Feature{ m_value });
    }

    ++m_value;
}
```